# AgGrid get params for cellEditorParams from async function

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a problem with the CellEditorSelector. When I call the cell editing mode, I need to call the cell renderer with the new parameters. I want to get some parameters from an async function. I try to do it, but there is no "values" in the parameters

```
columnDefs: [
    {
      cellEditor: MyEditor,
      cellEditorParams: {
        values: async function (params: any) { return await table.getParams(params.rowIndex); }
      },
```